# How deploy Spring boot SSL project in openshift

Tags: java, spring-boot, openshift

I have a spring project with SSL on by which i mean:

in my application.properties

```
security.require-ssl=true
```

So locally if i run it, like http://localhost:8080, i get

```
Bad Request
This combination of host and port requires TLS.
```

If i run it **https**://localhost:8080, It works.

I was trying to deploy this project to **openshift**

In my Dockerfile,

```
Expose 8080
```

in my openshift deployment yaml file:

```
a deployment config with 
ports:
 - containerPort: 8080
   protocol: TCP

- kind: Service
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
      name: APP_NAME
    spec:
      ports:
        - name: http
          port: 80
          protocol: TCP
          targetPort: 8080
      selector:
        app: APP_NAME
        deploymentconfig: APP_NAME
```

When i create route in openshift which is a **https** route and lets say it is: **https://springboot-sample-boot.opnshift.com** and go to it, i get:

```
Bad Request
This combination of host and port requires TLS.
```

and it uses these routes:
ports:

```
- name: http
  port: 80
  protocol: TCP
  targetPort: 8080
```

As my knowledge, the openshift routes/url is listening to port 80 which redirects to containers 8080 port.

I see in the pods, https route is open in 8080:

```
Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (https) with context path ''
```

But openshift https route is not correctly routing to pods.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Just from the top of my head, it looks like you've wrong configuration for redirecting on openshift or docker as it doesn't redirect the urls as required. Please add the URLs you go with on OpenShift.

Comment: you are asking for the openshift url i go to access my application?

Comment: nope, I'm speaking about "which is a https route and go to it" - so when you try to request your app on openshift, which protocol (http/https) and which port you use?

Comment: I updated it in the my post.

Comment: Can you show us the route definition? I believe that, by default, a route is `edge` terminated, meaning that it's https to the HAProxy router, but http to your pod. If you update the route to either be `reencrypt` or `passthrough` if should work as expected

Comment: @WillGordon, it did work with `passthrough`. i haven't tried with `reencrypt` yet. Thank you all for your help

Comment: But with passthrough You don't have green lock in url address ( Your application traffic isn't encrypted)

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I ran into the same problem.